# Variable with an input’s value is empty when assigned outside a function

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I recently created an input box in HTML:

```html
<input type="number" id="aa" onchange="yy()">
<p id="xx"></p>
```

Then I called the following code:

```js
var gg = document.getElementById("aa").value;

function yy(){
  document.getElementById("xx").innerHTML = gg;
}
```

Nothing appeared.

However if I change the script into:

```js
function yy(){
  gg = document.getElementById("aa").value;
  document.getElementById("xx").innerHTML = gg;
}
```

It worked!

I thought that if I declared the variable `gg` first (global), I could use the value in the `yy` function. Why does the first code not behave like the second code?

Comment: When enter page with this code, variable gg has a initial value from input - i suppose it is empty. So variable gg is empty.So when u make changes on this input u invoke the function yy() which changes value of paragraph XX with value of GG which is defined as empty. In the second example you invoke function yy() and u set the variable's gg value to the current input's value and set the paragraph's HTML to be as gg

Comment: Got it.. thank you for the explanation @mamosek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you didn't put the value inside the function. Now `var gg` will always hold the initial value. Which is on page load empty.

By putting it inside the function. The value will be retrieved as soon as the function gets triggered. In your case, you putted a `onchange` trigger on it.

So when the value changes, the function will run at that moment, and retrieves the value inside the input field.

**You can only get something if you ask for it**. *Or in this case* **JavaScript can only get something if something asks for it**

Your function in the first case doens't ask for a value. In your seconds case, `JavaScript` asks the `value` of element `#aa`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @Red. 
The thought on my head (CMIIWW) is that when I run 1st scenario, when I updated the content in the input field, the function 'yy' is triggered and called var 'gg' and yet I have not define 'gg' (line above the function line) so nothing returned.
Is my concept correct @Red?

Thank you.

Comment: You defined `gg`. But before the function. So `var gg` will just be retrieved at page load. It will not update itself if it changed. You will understand these things one day ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `gg` inside `yy` function. But the thing here is the value you have inside `gg`. Since you are calling

```
var gg = document.getElementById("aa").value;
```

on page load, the input element do not have any value so the value of `gg` is always blank. And now when you change the value for `id="aa"` you are using the value of `gg` for its `innerHTML` and you always get blank. Now, the only fix is that, since your `innerHTML` depends on value of `gg` (Which is for input with id aa), you must include this inside your `change()` function to get correct output. Thus, the reason is not that you cannot access or get the value of global variable- you can but in this case the value is incorrect as expected.

For proper verification and understanding here is an example that has the value of `id='aa'` already specified then when you change the input then you get to see the value of `gg`:

```js
var gg = document.getElementById("aa").value;
function yy(){
  document.getElementById("xx").innerHTML=(gg);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="aa" onchange="yy()" value='123'>
<p id="xx"></p>
```

Comment: But if the code written this way, then the value retrieved will be always '123'.
 But thank you for the explanation ^_^

Comment: That is what i am trying to explain. The example is just to prove the OP that the global variable is accessible from within the function, and nothing else.